# How to add line numbers to input file

Tags: java, file-io, string-formatting

So i am writing a method that takes in a file input and a file output. Reads the input file and adds  line numbers to the lines so it should read "   1 | LINE" so the number is right aligned 3 spaces followed by number and a "|" with a space before and after it. I am having trouble printing out the line. My code so far is:

```
public class LineNumbers {
    public static void process(File input, File output) {
        ArrayList<String> fileInput = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        int counter = 0;
        int counter1= 1;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileInput.add(scanner.nextLine());
                String a = fileInput.get(counter);
                String line = String.format("%3s | " ,counter1,a);
                out.add(line);
                counter++;
                counter1++;
                for(String n:fileInput){                    
                    writer.println(n);
                }

            }
            scanner.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
String.format("%3s | " ,counter1,a);
```

You pass `a` as a parameter but you have not told `String.format()` what to do with it, and so it does nothing.

I do not see a format specifier corresponding to `a`. You most probably mean:

```
String.format("%3s | %s" ,counter1,a);
```

Comment: right above that line it has String a = fileInput.get(counter); what do you mean format-specifier?

Comment: @user3511198 Yes, and I do not see a format specifier for `a`.

Comment: *"What do you mean format-specifier?"* I mean "format specifier" in the same way it is used in the [documentation for `String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: This works for the first line, so it is working, but it is not iterating through for the 2nd line and line number

Comment: @user3511198 Then it sounds like you have more than one problem, but it is difficult for us to tell that because you have only said "I am having trouble printing out the line" and nothing more. Please edit your question to describe your problem clearly.

Comment: well i didn't the problem because it wasn't even printing

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, to add line number to each line. The following code will work for you.

```
public static void process(File input, File output)
{
    try
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
        int counter = 1;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            String line = String.format("%3s | %s", counter, nextLine);
            counter++;
            writer.println(line);
        }
        scanner.close();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Feeding [help vampires](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) makes our site worse as a whole.